# Validation is occuring again after clicking on submit button in angular dev extreme

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular

I am having a page with textboxes and validations  . When i click on submit button , the values inside textbox pass to the db but the validations are appearing again after the click on submit button . I am using .net core with dev extreme angular . This problem is occuring in angular. The validations keep occuring on the textbox even after submit button is clicked . I have used formreset method and setvalue as well on my save function but it is not working . Any help or suggestions would be useful.

I have used formname.controls.setvalue('') and formreset() and clear() but its not working .
i am using dev extreme angular . what to use for this.

Answer (score -1):

Check Form Validation or Validate angular form status try Updating it
console.log('Form valid:', myForm.valid);
console.log('Form invalid:', myForm.invalid);
Check reactive form changes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).